# Immutable StencilJS Props re-render when changed

Tags: stenciljs

I have the following StencilJS component with three properties.

```
import { Component, h, Prop } from "@stencil/core";

@Component({
  tag: 'twl-button',
  styleUrls: ['../style-tw.dist.css', './twl-button.scss'],
  scoped: true
})
export class ButtonComponent {

  @Prop() isBoolean: boolean = false;
  @Prop() aNumber: number = -1;
  @Prop() aString: string = "a"

  componentWillLoad() {
    alert(`componentWillLoad: ${this.isBoolean} | ${this.aNumber} | ${this.aString}`)
  }

  render() {
    alert(`rendering: ${this.isBoolean} | ${this.aNumber} | ${this.aString}`)
    return (
      <button onClick={() => this.didClick()}class={'w-1/3 self-center flex justify-center mt-1/12 py-2 px-2 border border-transparent font-normal text-lg rounded-md text-white bg-nord9 hover:bg-nord14 focus:outline-none focus:border-nord9 focus:shadow-outline-gray active:bg-nord10 transition duration-150 ease-in-out'}>
        Click to Change
      </button>
    );
  }

  didClick(): void {
    this.isBoolean = !this.isBoolean;
    this.aNumber = this.aNumber+1;
    this.aString = this.aString+"b";
  }
}
```

It's used in JSX as:
`<twl-button isBoolean={true} aNumber={0} aString={"init-string"}></twl-button>`

My understanding reading the StencilJS documentation is that these properties are implicitly immutable.  I would think that an immutable property would also imply no-rendering, since nothing changes.  However, when I click the button, the values change and render is called. Where is my misunderstanding?

pacakge.json:

```
...
"@stencil/core": "^1.17.3",
"@stencil/router": "^1.0.1",
"@stencil/sass": "^1.3.2",
...
```

Comment: You're right about [the docs](https://stenciljs.com/docs/properties#prop-mutability) but after a quick search through the source I believe mutating a property [only shows a console warning (and only in dev builds)](https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/blob/f6437b384f0c65c3bc9edaa06dfc36deb998aefb/src/runtime/proxy-component.ts#L34). Not sure why though.

Answer (score 4):

You can think of the `@Prop()` decorator itself as creating a `watch` on the property (`isBoolean`, `aNumber`, `aString` in your case), and every time a value is assigned to it, the `watch` performs an equality check (`===`) on the old value and new value to determine if the value has changed (and therefore, whether a re-render is needed).

You would not see the same behavior if your prop was an object and you set a value on the object `@Prop()` because even though one of the values has changed, the `===` reference returns `true` since the object reference remains the same

```js
@Prop() user: IUser = {
  firstName: 'user',
  lastName: 'name'
};

...
...

// does not trigger a re-render (since object reference remains unchanged)
user.firstName = 'new user';   


// triggers a re-render (because you are essentially creating a new object and assigning it to the user property)
user = {
  ...user,
  firstName = 'new user'
};
```